# alexa skill development using https endpoint

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have already built amazon alexa skills using aws lambda, now I want to build a skill using https endpoint. I don't have a clear vision how to proceed further. Can anyone guide / give me steps to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You have mainly two choices to start as mentioned here

1. Write your own implementation for the Alexa endpoint json interface contract. By saying that, I mean you will write the endpoint to accept the json request from alexa, parse and consume it, and generate a json response that is both syntatically and logically correct to be consumed by your Alexa skill. For input/output json format, read this further:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html

2. The second choice is to avoid to reinvent the wheel of writing your own json interface contract implementation, and to use a library or client sdk. Using this approach will provide you APIs in your desired langauge to both consume and build the request responses for an Alexa endpoint. As you have tagged node.js in your question, so here is one such client sdk

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Please flip through [this detailed description of a project](https://github.com/AlexXiong97/alexa-skill-with-arduino-webclient) with similar requirements. This documentation includes each steps you'll need to take.

In short, you need to set up **Amazon API Gateway** with your Alexa Skill, which will hook up your lambda function with a publicly addressable API.

If the other endpoint only accepts and sends HTTP instead of HTTPS requests, you will further need **Amazon CloudFront** as a proxy relayer.